# How do I replace this raw loop with an STL algorithm or iterators? (avoiding unchecked subscript operator)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20

I'm implementing a generic clone of [the Snake game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game_genre)) in C++ as an exercise in following the C++ Recommended Guidelines. I'm currently working on the Snake's update() method, which is tiggering a Guideline-violation for using the unchecked subscript operator in a for loop:

> Prefer to use gsl::at() instead of unchecked subscript operator
> ([bounds.4](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#probounds-bounds-safety-profile)).

I want to avoid the redundant range change check of gsl::at() / container::at(), and don't want to suppress the warning either. With that in mind, **how can I replace this raw loop with something more Guideline-friendly?** (eg. an STL algorithm, iterators, what have you)

```
void Snake::update() noexcept {  
  if (hasTrailingSegments()) {
    for (auto i = body_segments.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      body_segments[i] = body_segments[i - 1];
    }
  }  
  head() += heading;  
}
```

The code explained, bottom up:

- the loop needs to ensure each body segment follows (= takes the position of) the one in front of it.
- body_segments is a std::vector of integer pairs.
- hasTrailingSegments() ensure that "trailing_pieces" is size() > 1 (eg. player has more than just the head).
- head() is simply body_segments[0]

Comment: [`std::copy_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward)?

Comment: This looks more like a rotation, in which case, `std::rotate()` is the better fit. `std::ranges:rotate()` if C++20 is in play.

Comment: Your algorithm completes with `body_segments[0]` equal to `body_segments[1]`.  Is that important?  Does it matter what is in `body_segments[0]`?  This may be a call for effectively `std::shift_right`.

Comment: A more efficient solution might be to use a `std::deque` instead of a `std::vector`. You can pop the last element off the back and push the new head position onto the front in constant time. I'm not sure if you can keep the `noexcept` though, and it doesn't work if you need the data to be contiguous.

Comment: @sweenish : The last element is discarded rather than moved to the front so I'd say `std::shift_right()` is the better fit.

Comment: @ildjarn I think you're right. I was unaware of the `shift_*()` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `std::rotate` the snake so that the old tail is the front element, and then overwrite that with the new segment.

```
void Snake::update() noexcept {
  auto new_head = head() + heading;
  std::rotate(body_segments.begin(), body_segments.end() - 1, body_segments.end());
  head() = std::move(new_head);
}
```

Alternatively, you can `copy_backward` the body, overwriting the tail.

```
void Snake::update() noexcept {
  std::copy_backward(body_segments.begin(), body_segments.end() - 1, body_segments.end());
  head() += heading;
}
```

These are safe so long as a `Snake` always has at least one segment, which `head()` requires anyway.

Comment: That is gorgeous! Thanks.

Question regarding your edit (adding a move). A segment is just a struct {int, int} - a trivial type. A move makes no difference here, right?

Comment: @ulfben yes, but if it ever stops being trivial it can matter